# Javascript function returning multiple outputs for same for loop iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

(I am new to coding and trying to learn, this is my first question here. I hope I am clear enough)
I am trying to make a function that takes in an array of numbers and returns a string depending on how many elements in the array

for example `const temps1 = [17, 21, 23];`

and to return `'...17°C in 1 days ...21°C in 2 days ...23°C 3 days'` and so on

this is the code I have written:

```
const temps1 = [17, 21, 23];

const temps2 = [12, 5, -5, 0, 4];

const printForecast = function (temps) {
  let displayer = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < temps.length; i++) {
    displayer.push(`...${temps[i]}°C in ${i + 1} days`);

    console.log(displayer.join(' '));

    // const displayer = [`...${temps[i]}°C in ${i + 1} days`];
  }
};
```

This is the output:

```
...17°C in 1 days

...17°C in 1 days ...21°C in 2 days

...17°C in 1 days ...21°C in 2 days ...23°C in 3 days

-

...12°C in 1 days

...12°C in 1 days ...5°C in 2 days

...12°C in 1 days ...5°C in 2 days ...-5°C in 3 days

...12°C in 1 days ...5°C in 2 days ...-5°C in 3 days ...0°C in 4 days

...12°C in 1 days ...5°C in 2 days ...-5°C in 3 days ...0°C in 4 days ...4°C in 5 days

(index):55 Live reload enabled.
```

Comment: You've got the `console.log()` call **inside** the loop. If you just want to log the result after the loop is finished, the call should be after the loop, not inside.